# Use induction to prove that $3|(4^n − 1) $ for any integer $n \geq 0$

Tags: logic, induction

Use induction to prove that :

> $ 3 |(4^n − 1)$ for any integer $n ≥ 0$

Hint: If $k \geq 0$ is an integer then
$4^{(k+1)} = 4\cdot4^k = 3 \cdot4^k + 4^k$.

Honestly have no idea how to even start this one

Comment: What does your '|' mean here?

Comment: I think he means $3$ divides $4n-1$.

Comment: I guess divide @Yannik

Comment: But $4\cdot 2 -1 =7$..

Comment: '|' means "divisible by"

Comment: For induction you need to prove (a) a base case - so with $n=0$ here, because the result is wanted for $n\ge 0$; and (b) a successor step - to show that if the statement is true for $n=N$ then it is also true for $n=N+1$. You should be able to use the hint you have been given to show that you can reduce the divisibility for $n=N+1$ to the case of $n=N$ and hence prove the successor step. For the base case just put $n=0$ and see what you get.

Comment: "Honestly have no idea how to even start this one"....so you know nothing at all about induction or divisibility?  What kind of help are you expecting?

Comment: already got help for this question. thanks for your concern though

Answer (score 1):

**Using Induction**

1. For $k = 0$, we have $3|0$, which is true.
2. Assume $3|(4^{k}-1)$. So we can say $4^k -1 = 3q$
3. Now multiply both sides by $4$ :

$$\begin{align}4^{k+1}-4 &= 12q \\
\implies4^{k+1} -1 &= 3(4q+1)\end{align}$$

Thus $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ so that $P(k)$ is true for all naturals.

---

**Using Binomial Theorem**

I think you seek to prove  $3 | (4^k - 1)$. Consider the binomial expansion of $(4-1)^{k}$

$$(4-1)^k = \binom{k}{0}4^k  - \binom{k}{1} 4^{k-1} \dots (-1)^k\binom{k}{k}$$

Now take case for odd and even $k$.

1. For odd $k$, $3^k = 4q-1$. Hence we get our result.
2. For even $k$, $3^k = 4q+1 =4(q-1)+6-1$. Then again our result follows

Comment: Oops didn't see that. :(

Comment: For $k=0$, $4^k-1 \neq 3$

Comment: +1 but $\begin{align}4^{k+1}-4 &= 12q \\
\implies4^{k+1} -1 &= 3(4q+1)\end{align}$ you don't need another variable

Comment: @Isham Yeah its better written that way!

Answer (score 1):

Base Case : $n=0$,$~3 \vert 0$ is true.

Now suppose $3 \vert 4^n -1$ for some $n \ge 0$.

We've to prove $3 \vert 4^{n+1}-1$ is also true.

$3 \vert 4^{n}-1 \implies 3 \vert4(4^n-1) \implies 3 \vert4(4^n-1)-3 \implies 3 \vert4^{n+1}-1$

Hence proved :)

Comment: Nice and clean :)

Answer (score 1):

if $n=1$ it is true because $4^1-1=3$

Now suppose that $4^n -1$ is a multiple of $3$ and let's prove that

$4^{n+1}-1$ is a multiple of $3$, too $\quad(*)$

The inductive hypothesis is that $4^n -1$ is a multiple of $3$ that is $4^n-1=3k$ for some $k$ we can write as $4^n=3k+1$

back to $(*)$

$4^{n+1}-1=4\cdot 4^n -1=4(3k+1)-1=12k+4-1=12k+3=3(4k+1)$

which proves that $4^{n+1}-1$ is a multiple of $3$

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it using modular arithmetics

1. $k=0$, $4^0-1=0$ and $3 \mid 0$
2. $k=1$, i.e. $4 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ (which is the same as $3 \mid 4 -1$)
3. we assume it is true for $4^k \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ (which is the same as $3 \mid 4^k -1$)
4. from $(2)$ and $(3)$ and the fact that $\color{red}{a \equiv b \pmod{n} \text{ and } c \equiv d \pmod{n} \Rightarrow ac \equiv bd \pmod{n}}$ we have
   $$4^k \cdot 4 \equiv 1\cdot 1 \pmod{3}$$ or $$4^{k+1} \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \Leftrightarrow 3 \mid 4^{k+1}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

The hint says it all.

Let $ k = 0 $, then $4^k \equiv 1 \mod 3$.

Suppose, for $k=n$ you have $4^k \equiv 1 \mod 3$, now
for $k = n+1$, per hint $$4^{n+1} = 3 \cdot 4^n + 4^n \equiv 4^n \equiv 1 \mod 3$$

What that mean is $$4^n - 1 = 3 \cdot m$$ for some natural $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The case $k = 0$ is self-evident: $3 \mid 0$.

Consider that

$3 \mid 4 - 1, \tag 1$

which is the case $k = 1$;. then since we have

$4(4^k - 1) + 3 = 4^{k + 1} - 4 + 3 = 4^{k + 1} - 1, \tag 2$

if we assume

$3 \mid 4^k - 1, \tag 3$

and recall as in (1) that

$3 \mid 3, \tag 4$

we see that

$3 \mid 4(4^k - 1) + 3 \tag 5$

directly follows.  Thus, *via* (2), we obtain

$3 \mid 4^{k + 1} - 1; \tag 6$

So much for an inductive proof of (6).  As simple as this is, an even simpler (non-inductive) proof may be had by observing that

$4^{k + 1} - 1 = (2^2)^{k + 1} - 1 = (2^{k + 1})^2 - 1 = (2^{k + 1} - 1)(2^{k + 1} + 1), \tag 7$

and that $3$ must divide at least one of the three consecutive integers

$2^{k + 1} - 1, 2^{k + 1}, 2^{k + 1} + 1; \tag 8$

since $3 \not \mid 2^{k + 1}, \tag 9$

we must have

$3 \mid 2^{k + 1} - 1 \vee 3 \mid 2^{k + 1} + 1, \tag{10}$

and in either case we see that

$3 \mid (2^{k + 1} - 1)(2^{k + 1} + 1), \tag{11}$

from which, by (7), (6) becomes evident as well.